# Searching text for a list of a phrases in Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to search over a text field to check if any of the phrases in the search list are in the text field. If they exist as a whole word match, the query should return True else it should return false.

Example:
Search list - 'at bat', 'at ball'

Currently if i use the following regex in Redshift,

```
SELECT text_field ~ 'at bat|at ball' FROM table
```

it matches on partial terms as well. Example - at batting . I tried the following as well,

```
SELECT text_field ~ '(^|\\W)(at bat|at ball)(\\W|$)' FROM table
```

and i do not get matches on any of the rows I should be getting matches on. Whats the best way to search for whole word phrases in Redshift? text_field is all in lower case.

Comment: Try `\b(at bat|at ball)\b`

Comment: This does not work on redshift. List of operations available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Comment: `\\b` and `(^|\\W)` work in `regexp_instr` but not `~`

Answer (score 1):

The `~` (*tilde*) operator supports a limited set of regular expression syntax.

Recommend using the `REGEXP_INSTR` function instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html

```
select venuename, regexp_instr(venuename,'[cC]ent(er|re)$') 
from venue 
where regexp_instr(venuename,'[cC]ent(er|re)$') > 0 
limit 5;
```